# Trying to grab data from two columns and format them properly

Tags: sql

So I have a database here with a table that lists off whether or not certain processes have failed. There are two columns, IsProcessed, and IsFailed. A failed process can still be considered processed if the error was handled, but I still need to recognize that it failed. They're both bit values, and so I have to try and grab and separate them despite that they may depend on one another. After they've been separated out, I need to count the relative successes and relative failures.

I utilize an AND statement in my WHERE clause to try and separate out the successes from the failures. I honestly have no idea where to go from here.

```
SELECT CAST(PQ.ProcessedDate AS Date) AS Date, COUNT(PQ.IsProcessed) AS Successes
FROM PQueue PQ
WHERE PQ.ProcessDate BETWEEN '2019-10-1' AND '2019-10-31' AND PQ.IsFailed = 0 AND PQ.IsProcessed = 1
GROUP BY CAST(PQ.ProcessDate AS Date)
ORDER BY CAST(PQ.ProcessDate AS Date) ASC
```

Because a failed process can still be processed in the system, we have to do a check first to try and grab the data that was processed but didn't flag a failure. Now I need to try and find a way to not exclude the failures, but include them and place them in a group. I can do the group part, but I'm relatively new to SQL so I don't know whether or not I can place something in an IF statement somewhere or try to use variables to get this done. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You described what you have, but not what you want.  What is the desired outcome?  Can you provide sample input and [desired] output data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CAST(PQ.ProcessedDate AS Date) AS Date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PQ.IsFailed = 0 AND PQ.IsProcessed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Successes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PQ.IsFailed = 1 AND PQ.IsProcessed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Fails
FROM PQueue PQ
WHERE PQ.ProcessDate BETWEEN '2019-10-1' AND '2019-10-31'
GROUP BY CAST(PQ.ProcessDate AS Date)
ORDER BY CAST(PQ.ProcessDate AS Date) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If SQL Server then maybe a CASE statement would help you out.

eg

SELECT ...........
CASE
  WHEN IsFailed = 1 AND IsProcessed = 1 THEN "Processed But Failed"
  WHEN IsFailed = 0 AND IsProcessed = 0 THEN "Not Processed"
  WHEN IsFailed = 0 AND IsProcessed = 1 THEN "Processed Succesfully"
  WHEN IsFailed = 1 AND IsProcessed = 0 THEN "Failed"
END as REsult